# Adding fading "tooltips" to website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm a beginning web developer and I just completed my first website. It is pretty simple, and lacks in functionality. You can see it here: http://www.amritayalur.com. On the right, I have a few social media icons in a column. I want to use jQuery to display some text that labels the icon. For example, I think it would be really cool if when the Twitter icon was moused over, some small text on the left reading "Twitter" would fade in with an arrow pointing towards the icon. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: *khmm* http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+fading+tooltips

Comment: [worried] SO will soon become a broken links collection! ...  :| [/worried]

Comment: Decided to go with the Tipsy tooltip plug-in eventually. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [dozens of jQuery tooltip plugins](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/) out there. I recommend you search one that fits your needs.

Personally, I found out that at first glance they all look rather identical, but when it comes to the "API" design (and documentation) there are huge differences. Also, take a look at when they last updated their code. Using a library that way updated in 2008 for the last time always makes me feel kind of uncomfortable.

In my last project I used [**this**](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) jQuery tooltip library.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/566kZ/

Something along the lines of:

```
<style>
.tooltip {
[various styles]
opacity:0;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".socialLink").hover(
    function () { 
      $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().animate({opacity: 1},500);
    },
    function () { 
      $(this).find(".tooltip").stop().animate({opacity: 0},500);
  });
});
</script>

<a href="twitter.com" class="socialLink">
<img src="twitter.jpg" />
<div class="tooltip">Twitter</div>
</a>
```

With some fairly simple styling of tooltip, you could achieve the effect you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

It's include jQuery so you don't have to include the library if you include jQuery Tools. It has some other very handy stuff too if you're interested.

Comment: I saw this, but these tooltips are a bit bulky if you know what I mean. I don't want an actual tooltip, just some text with a curved arrow pointing to the icon. I can't seem to find an example of this, but I have seen it before.

Answer (score 0):

qTip is a jQuery tooltip plugin which you can try

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/